# Gaps after adding canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

[when I am adding canvas to my GUI there are appear some weird gaps between buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ytMx.png)  It doesn't appear without canvas(red one).

```
for i in range(1,30):
    self.przyciskiZawodnikow.append(Button(root, width=w, text="chuj", compound="bottom", height=h, image=self.obrazy_wlosow['blond'], borderwidth=b, command =lambda i=i: self.aktual_stat(i)))
    self.przyciskiZawodnikow[-1].grid(row=0, column=i-1)

self.boisko = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100, background='red')
self.boisko.grid(row=5, sticky='S')

self.boisko = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100, background='red')
self.boisko.grid(row=5, sticky='S')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creating a grid, which means every cell in a column will be the same width, and ever cell in a row will be the same height.

When you put the canvas in column 0 (by virtue of not specifying the column), that forces column 0 to be as wide as the canvas. Since your buttons aren't as wide as the canvas, and you haven't specified any other options, the buttons will be centered in their cell. Thus, any extra space will be allocated equally on each side of the button in column zero.